# Pop up window in MVC3 Razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I a have code segment :

```
<button class="awe-btn" onclick="<%:Url.Awe().PopupFormAction().Url(Url.Action("create")).Success("create").Title("create dinner") %>">Create</button>
```

that are MVC axps page I want to similar code for MVC Razor view engine. Any one Suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button class="awe-btn" onclick="@Url.Awe().PopupFormAction().Url(Url.Action("create")).Success("create").Title("create dinner")">Create</button>
```

Comment: Serg Rogovtsev I try this way but  i get a exception for "Awe()"

Comment: Would you please show use (a) your code (b) exception you're getting?

Comment: my error message are : CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Awe' and no extension method 'Awe' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And what is `Awe()`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @csefaruk *that* I see. But where does it come from in your original code?